# FFmpeg ignore audio export if no stream present

Tags: ffmpeg

I am converting/scaling a video with ffmpeg and also exporting the audio stream to a single audio file.

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg  -i video.mov -vf  scale="480:480"   -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -preset ultrafast -crf 22 -c:a aac  -pix_fmt yuv420p -y video-output.mp4  -y audio-output.mp3
```

However, if the video is lacking an audio file, it breaks.

Is there a way to ignore the audio export if no audio is present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a conditional mapping operator `-map "0:a?"`, so for example this creates an output file without audio if the input stream has no audio (and the `-c:a` option will be ignored):

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc -c:v libx264 -map "0:a?" -c:a aac out.mkv
```

However, if you want to have more than one output file like in your example, you have to programmatically detect that before constructing the command. Otherwise ffmpeg will complain about your second output file not containing any stream.

For example:

```
ffprobe <input> -loglevel error \
  -show_streams -show_entries stream=codec_type \
  -of compact=nk=1:p=0
```

This will print a line containing `audio` if the input file has an audio stream. Of course there are other ways to parse the output of `ffmpeg` for streams.

Comment: Great! But I also had to include video, and include audio only if present/can be encoded without errors. So I used: `-map "0:v" -map "0:a?"`

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to split the task into two lines, one for the video and one for the audio. If the audio fails, it just moves on.